# How do I use the MAX function over three tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, I have a problem with a SQL Query.

It's about getting weather data for German cities. I have 4 tables: staedte (the cities with primary key loc_id), gehoert_zu (contains the city-key and the key of the weather station that is closest to this city (stations_id)), wettermessung (contains all the weather information and the station's key value) and wetterstation (contains the stations key and location). And I'm using PostgreSQL

Here is how the tables look like:

```
wetterstation
s_id[PK]   standort    lon    lat    hoehe 
----------------------------------------
10224      Bremen      53.05  8.8    4


wettermessung
stations_id[PK]    datum[PK]     max_temp_2m   ......
----------------------------------------------------
10224              2013-3-24     -0.4


staedte
loc_id[PK]    name    lat    lon
-------------------------------
15            Asch    48.4   9.8


gehoert_zu
loc_id[PK]    stations_id[PK]
-----------------------------
15            10224
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the name of the city with the (for example) highest temperature at a specified date (could be a whole month, or a day). Since the weather data is bound to a station, I actually need to get the station's ID and then just choose one of the corresponding to this station cities. A possible question would be: "In which city was it hottest in June ?" and, say, the highest measured temperature was in station number 10224. As a result I want to get the city Asch. What I got so far is this

```
SELECT name, MAX (max_temp_2m)
FROM wettermessung, staedte, gehoert_zu 
WHERE wettermessung.stations_id = gehoert_zu.stations_id
    AND gehoert_zu.loc_id = staedte.loc_id 
    AND wettermessung.datum BETWEEN '2012-8-1' AND '2012-12-1' 
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY MAX (max_temp_2m) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

There are two problems with the results: 
1) it's taking waaaay too long. The tables are not that big (cities has about 70k entries), but it needs between 1 and 7 minutes to get things done (depending on the time span)
2) it ALWAYS produces the same city and I'm pretty sure it's not the right one either.

I hope I managed to explain my problem clearly enough and I'd be happy for any kind of help. Thanks in advance ! :D

Comment: You are using `LIMIT 1` so you will always return one row and you are ordering the data by the `max` so you will always return the same row.  If you remove the `LIMIT 1` do you get all of the rows you expect.

Comment: Well, the weather data is bound to a station and then the station to a city, so I have about 1000 cities for every station. If I remove the limit I get all the cities that are bound to this station, but the data is the same for all of them.

Comment: My suggestion would be to edit your original post with some sample data for each table and the desired result.

Comment: I'd suggest to add an index for `wettermessung.datum` to improve speed.

Comment: What is max_windgeschwindigkeit?  Where does it come from?  Why is it in the group by?

Comment: Sorry, got left behind from old tries, should not be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the max temperature per city use this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT gz.loc_id, MAX(max_temp_2m) as temperature
      FROM wettermessung as wm
      INNER JOIN gehoert_zu as gz
         ON wm.stations_id = gz.stations_id
      WHERE wm.datum BETWEEN '2012-8-1' AND '2012-12-1' 
      GROUP BY gz.loc_id) as subselect
   INNER JOIN staedte as std
      ON std.loc_id = subselect.loc_id
      ORDER BY subselect.temperature DESC
```

Use this statement to get the city with the highest temperature (only 1 city):

```
SELECT * FROM(
   SELECT name, MAX(max_temp_2m) as temp
   FROM wettermessung as wm
   INNER JOIN gehoert_zu as gz
      ON wm.stations_id = gz.stations_id
   INNER JOIN staedte as std
      ON gz.loc_id = std.loc_id
   WHERE wm.datum BETWEEN '2012-8-1' AND '2012-12-1' 
   GROUP BY name
   ORDER BY MAX(max_temp_2m) DESC 
   LIMIT 1) as subselect
ORDER BY temp desc
LIMIT 1
```

For performance reasons always use explicit joins as LEFT, RIGHT, INNER JOIN and avoid to use joins with separated table name, so your sql serevr has not to guess your table references.

Comment: Yes, this works, but it gives me ALL the max values from ALL the stations. Is there a way to find the highest MAX value and get JUST that one ? I'm asking mostly because it runs for almost 10 minutes, I get the highest value anyway. And thanks A LOT for the help !

Comment: You could surround the whole statement with a new select. I edited the statement above.. ;-)
But this will only reduce the time to deliver your data, not the calculation time...

Comment: Do you want the top temperature of everything or per city?

Comment: Wow, the second query is ready in seconds and I still get the city with the highest temp, so that's just awesome ! Thanks again for the solutions, you saved my life (actually, the semester, but it's still pretty big ! :D )

Comment: Your welcome! And don't forget to vote for my solution.. ;-)
(It was also nice to solve your problem as preparation for my semester exam tomorrow.. ;-)

Comment: Apparently I need 15 rep to vote it, so, sorry, can't even though I want to... And good look at the exam, but it seems you'll do just fine ! :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a general example of how to get the item with the highest, lowest, biggest, smallest, whatever value.  You can adjust it to your particular situation.

```
select fred, barney, wilma
from bedrock join
(select fred, max(dino) maxdino
from bedrock
where whatever
group by fred ) flinstone on bedrock.fred = flinstone.fred
where dino = maxdino
and other conditions
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose you use a consistent naming convention. Singular terms for tables holding a single item per row is a good convention. You only table breaking this is `staedte`. Should be `stadt`.

And I suggest to use `station_id` consistently instead of either `s_id` and `stations_id`.

Building on these premises, for your question:

> ... get the name of the city with the ... highest temperature at a specified date

```
SELECT s.name, w.max_temp_2m
FROM  (
   SELECT station_id, max_temp_2m
   FROM   wettermessung
   WHERE  datum >= '2012-8-1'::date
   AND    datum <  '2012-12-1'::date       -- exclude upper border
   ORDER  BY max_temp_2m DESC, station_id  -- id as tie breaker
   LIMIT  1
   ) w
JOIN    gehoert_zu g USING (station_id) -- assuming normalized names
JOIN    stadt      s USING (loc_id)
```

- Use explicit `JOIN` conditions for better readability and maintenance.
- Use table aliases to simplify your query.
- Use `x >= a AND x < b` to include the lower border and exclude the upper border, which is the common use case.
- Aggregate first and pick your station with the highest temperature, before you join to the other tables to retrieve the city name. Much simpler and faster.
- You did not specify what to do when multiple "wettermessungen" tie on `max_temp_2m` in the given time frame. I added `station_id` as tiebreaker, meaning the station with the lowest id will be picked consistently if there are multiple qualifying stations.